# Transparent MOV files not appearing in my React webpage

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, vite, quicktime

I'm trying to use transparent video in React, I used **webM** initially but it doesn't support on some devices so I have tried moving over to **MOV**. However, cannot get it working in **React** + **Vite**. I have already tried adding this to my vite config `assetsInclude: ["**/*.mov"]` but they are still not appearing.

I created a lightweight project showing how its not working here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/flamboyant-gianmarco-9qngsy?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A19%2C13

Alternatively you can recreate the issue by testing the below version in any HTML previewer:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    test 1: <br>
    <video className="video">
    <source src="https://9qngsy-5173.csb.app/crown.mov" type="video/mov" />
    </video>
    
    <br> test 2: <br>
    <video className="video">
    <source src="https://9qngsy-5173.csb.app/crown.mov" type="video/quicktime" />
    </video>
    
    <br> test 3: <br>
    <video src="https://9qngsy-5173.csb.app/crown.mov" className="video">
    </video>
    
    <br> test 4: <br>
    <video className="video">
    <source src="https://9qngsy-5173.csb.app/crown.mov" type="video/quicktime" />
    </video>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *" I have tried moving over to mov. However, cannot get it working in **React** + **Vite**"*

Not all browsers support MOV files so test on a compatible browser.
For example Safari and Chrome will both play MOV, but you'll get no playback in Firefox (because it expects webM for video transparency).

> *" I have already tried adding ... but they are still not appearing."*

This line works to display your MOV inside the Chrome browser: 
*(no Apple device here to test on Safari browser, it might be more strict about needing a `type=` setting. Also the video's "transparency" channel itself was not tested).*

```
<video src="https://9qngsy-5173.csb.app/crown.mov" className="video">
</video>
```